# Como posso carregar arquivos de forma que eles funcionem em outros PCs mesmo que o caminho até o arquivo seja diferente? (Pygame)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Opa! Então... Eu estou fazendo um programa usando o **pygame**, e na hora de carregar um arquivo, eu devo usar isso, certo?

`bulletImg = pygame.image.load('C:\Users\Tarcísio\PycharmProjects\pyGameSpI\imgs\bullet.png')`

Mas isso só vai funcionar no meu computador, e não no computador de outras pessoas, porque o caminho até o arquivo é diferente. O que devo fazer?

Comment: Acredito que a função `load` aceite, também, caminhos relativos, então você não precisa informar o caminho absoluto da imagem. Se precisar do absoluto, pode utilizar a biblioteca `pathlib` para gerenciar isso.

Comment: Sim, eu consigo colocar ```'\imgs\bullet.png'``` e a IDE (Pycharm) ainda reconhece, mas quando tento rodar no CMD, só o caminho absoluto funciona

Answer (score 0):

O módulo `os`, mais especificamente seu método `path` é a sollução para este tipo de caso.

Uma enorme vantagem de utilizá-lo é a abstração do separador entre diretórios

```
import os

print(os.sep)
```

Nos sistema Linux e OSx o resultado seria: `/`

Enquanto no Windows: `\`

Sendo assim, você pode montar um diretório como: `f"primeiro{os.sep}segundo{os.sep}ultimo"`

O resultado poderia ser `primeiro/segundo/ultimo` ou `primeiro\segundo\ultimo`

Continuando. Você pode usar o `os.path.abspath` para pegar o caminho absoluto de algum caminho relativo.

Exemplo:

```
# o ponto passado como parâmetro corresponde ao diretório corrente
meu_diretorio = os.path.abspath(".")
```

No Linux e OSx, você terá algo como `/caminho/para/diretorio`
enquanto no Windows `C:\caminho\para\diretorio`

Com isso você poderia juntar uma string para fazer um novo diretório, conforme abaixo

```
meu_diretorio = os.path.abspath(".")

caminho_relativo = f"data{os.sep}arquivos"

arquivo = "nome_do_arquivo.ext"

full_path = os.path.join(meu_diretorio, caminho_relativo, arquivo)

print(full_path)
```

No Linux, o resultado seria algo como:

```
/caminho/para/diretorio/data/arquivos/nome_do_arquivo.ext
```

Já no Windows:

```
C:\caminho\para\diretorio\data\arquivos\nome_do_arquivo.ext
```

**Nota**: pode ser que a saída no Windows seja `C:\\caminho\\para\\diretorio\\data\\arquivos\\nome_do_arquivo.ext`, por conta de ter que "escapar" a `\`

Mais detalhes do `os.path` [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)